#  How do I share variables between classes?

Tags: java, android, variables, android-2.2-froyo

Say I am making something like a quiz, and I have a counter to show the number of questions that have been answered correctly.  When one question is correctly answered, and a new screen(Activity) is shown, how do I carry over the number to the next screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say screens do you mean Activities?  Then you probably want to pass them via extras in your intents.

Activity 1:

```
    int score;

    ...
    Intent Intent = new Intent(...);
    intent.putExtra("score_key", score);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Activity 2's `onCreate()`:

```
    int score;
    ...

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Read the extras data if it's available.
    if (extras != null)
    {
        score = extras.getInt("score_key");
    }
```

Comment: you can replace "score_key" with any String.  It is the key to identify that extra.  Just be sure your two keys match when you are putting and setting for the same data.

Answer (score 1):

You can send numbers, strings, etc in a bundle with your intent.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("testScore", numCorrect);
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent)
```

you can also put StringArrays and a few other simple vars

Answer (score 0):

One of this way you can share your data among whole project,

```
public class mainClass 
{
    private static int sharedVariable = 0;


    public static int getSharedVariable()
    {
          return sharedVariable;
    }
}
```

From the other class/activity , you can access it directly using classname and . (dot) operator. e.g. `mainClass.getSharedVariable();`

Answer (score 0):

A good practice for storing variables across Activitiys is using a own implementation of the Application Class.

```
public class MyApp extends android.app.Application {

private String myVariable;

public String getMyVariable() {
    return myVariable;
}

public void setMyVariable(String var) {
    this.myVariable = var;
}
```

Add the new Class in the Manifest.xml inside the application tag:

```
<application android:name="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Now you can manipulate the variable in every Activity as follows:

```
MyApp ctx = (MyApp)getApplicationContext();
String var = ctx.getMyVariable();
```