# android BroadCastReceiver how to send messages to listeners

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver which receive an internet state changes.

I want to be able to have a list of listeners in this receiver and to update the state of the internet in each one of them...

My problem that every time the receiver is called by the system, it makes a new instance of my class, and can't be referenced to the list of receivers I've created.

what's the best way of solving it?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9443063/802469) might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android linked list of listeners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959366/android-linked-list-of-listeners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try push notification system and if you want to have list of users try also UrbanAirShip.

Comment: I've actually thought of other idea.. how but putting the list as static ? it works, but does it a good solution ?

Comment: static may appear to work, but again, your entire app can be ejected from memory at any time. when that happens, you are back to square one. how or when it gets ejected depends on the specific device and what the user is doing.

Comment: the only thing i want to do is to change the internet state in my activity. when the internet is on it says :"on" and the same with off event. i've made and event implementation interface and that how supposed it should work..

Answer (score 1):

Receivers are intended to be stateless. you should assume the receiver object itself is destroyed after `onReceive()` returns. For memory purposes, Android doesn't keep your app sitting around in memory forever.

What you are trying to do is not possible. you are trying to implement the observable pattern on top of a receiver, except as you found out, you cannot keep track of the set of observers between invocations of the receiver.

It's hard to tell you how to solve it without knowing the larger context of your application. If the observers are all stateless objects, you could store the set of observer *types* in preferences, use a factory to re-instantiate them as needed. For example, in `onReceive()`,

```
String[] listeners = mPrefs.getString("listeners").split("|");
for (String l : listeners) {
  MyListener listener = ListenerFactory.obtain(l);
  listener.onWhatever(...);
}
```

Or you could use an SQLite database, whatever floats your boat.

Another idea is to serialize your listeners into an SQLite db as BLOBs as they are registered, deserialize them in the receiver perform the callback, and re-serialize into the DB.